# Why is my op-amp pulse generator (LF353) delivering way less voltage (±2 V) than the voltage supplies of the amplifier (±15 V)?

Tags: operational-amplifier, frequency, pulse, schmitt-trigger, square

I had to design the following circuit as a pulse generator so that if I vary the resistance the frequency will vary as well. It's defined by the frequency expression:

$$f=\frac{1}{2R_4C_1\ln(3)}$$

[image]

The frequency delivered is decent, but doesn't fully work for higher frequencies, but that's not the issue. What is giving me trouble is that when I simulate it and plot the output (Vo), it should be a square wave with amplitude closer to the supply voltages of the op-amp, but it's way below those values. I'm aware that something might be wrong with my circuit but I don't know what that is.

[image]

Comment: Your schematic shows an LF353 with $\pm$ 15V supplies.  Your simulation output and text appears to show $\pm$ 2V supplies.  Could you please *edit your question* to mention the op-amp that you're actually using, the supply voltages you're using (and if it's different in simulation and reality), the op-amp that you're using in your simulator, and the simulator you're using.

Comment: Posting your actual schematic would help, unless you're following what you've pictured except for the supply voltages.

Comment: Done!! I edited it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *I'm aware that something might be wrong with my circuit but I don't
> know what that is*

A 100 Ω load (R4) will scupper the output signal levels for an [**LF353**](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lf353.pdf?ts=1675020486826&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLF353%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Dasc-amps-null-prodfolderdynamic-cpc-pf-google-wwe_int%2526utm_content%253Dprodfolddynamic%2526ds_k%253DDYNAMIC%2BSEARCH%2BADS%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gclid%253DCj0KCQiAz9ieBhCIARIsACB0oGKxA6UwKYF_zfqdmRKCfv9GwGahqPs-P0K8jpJvsWtaNSJSc90DIioaAqqyEALw_wcB%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds): -

[image]

The same is true for the [**LF353-N**](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lf353-n.pdf): -

[image]

Although the information is presented somewhat differently.

Comment: Already modified my circuit and indeed, the output voltage is almost reaching 15V, which is great!! You know how can I limit the output current to be above 25mA? Currently is delivering 1.3mA and the design specifications state that it should be above that value.

Comment: "Limit my output ... 25mA".  Do you mean **boost** your output current?  That's really a separate question; if you can't find it answered already (I'm sure it is, but finding it would be a pain) ask -- something like "\$\pm\$ 25mA and \$\pm\$ 15V from an op-amp".

Comment: @ronny you need to add a driver stage if you want more output current. This can be done several ways so maybe ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks, i will do that, let's see how it goes.

Answer (score 5):

You need a different op-amp, a significantly higher output resistance (read the data sheet), or you need to augment the amplifier's output with a transistor amplifier stage.

If you just selected R4 to be that low at random, set it way higher.  While you're at it, adjust R1 through R3 upward by a factor of at least 2, maybe as much as 10.

(Note that the part is only specified to swing within 2.5V of each rail anyway -- if you need \$\pm\$15V, then you need to do something differently).

If you need to drive a 100 ohm load, and you really need to drive it to \$\pm\$12V (or worse, \$\pm\$15V) then you either need a high power output opamp (which ends up being kind of a boutique part) or you need to follow your pulse generation circuit with a power amplifier circuit.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the used amplifier for the maximum output current. You will realize that you actually capped by it. For example, TI datasheet show a figure very similiar to your simulated output https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lf353-n.pdf figure 28.